# cppwinrt constructor vs referencing the static method

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm trying to learn C++winrt. I am looking at the documentation and the c++ winrt docs here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata

One of the example shows that it gets a reference to a local folder by calling the constructor on storageFolder like this.

```cpp
StorageFolder m_localFolder{ Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder() };

IAsyncAction MainPage::WriteTimestampAsync()
{
    StorageFile sampleFile{ co_await m_localFolder.CreateFileAsync(L"dataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting) };
    // ....
}
```

In winRT c++ is there any difference to doing the following which is more similar to C#:

```
const auto m_localFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder();

IAsyncAction MainPage::WriteTimestampAsync()
{
    const auto sampleFile = co_await m_localFolder.CreateFileAsync(L"dataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Direct initialization (with the braces) and copy initialization (with the equals sign) are equivalent in this case. [They are subtly different in general](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization#Notes).

Comment: Is there any difference in this case since its a projected type?

Comment: There is no difference, they are equivalent.